# How to disable devtools in inertiajs and Laravel 8؟

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, devtools, inertiajs

How to disable devtools in inertiajs and Laravel 8؟
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Vue's devtools? If that so then I have two solution:

1. set `Vue.config.devtools` as `false` before you declare your app:

```js
import AppConfig from './app.vue';

Vue.config.devtools = false;
const App = new Vue(AppConfig);
```

2. Do not use development version and use production version instead. For more information please see [official Document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html#Getting-Started).

Each one above can achive your goal.

Comment: syntax usage is different for Laravel, vue and inertia

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

to .env file.

But why is it only applied in Firefox and Devtool are still visible in Chrome?

Comment: Please don’t include follow-up questions in your answers. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a discussion board, so the format doesn’t work well with follow-up questions outside of the comments.

Comment: The part of your answer that offers a solution is what [@John Chen suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69479444/3025856), so this is really a follow-up question for him, and should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: npm run production

Comment: If John Chen’s answer solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to his answer.